# Undocumented Wunderlist update user endpoint

Tags: wunderlist

There appears to be an endpoint on the Wunderlist API for updating the wunderlist user (at https://a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/user) which does not appear in the [official docs](https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation/endpoints/user)

User information can be updated by sending a `PUT` request to it, e.g. :

```
curl \
    -H "X-Access-Token: $WL_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -H "X-Client-ID: $WL_CLIENT_ID" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -XPUT -d '{"revision":1234,"name":"some-name"}' \
    https://a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/user
```

Assuming the data is valid, this returns with `HTTP 200`.

Is this endpoint supported?

Comment: Did you [contact them](https://support.wunderlist.com/customer/en/portal/emails/new)?

Comment: @JanDoggen thanks for the suggestion. It looks like that link is for general questions about using wunderlist - I cross-posted this question on the developer-centric [user api docs](https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation/endpoints/user) and will answer this if I get a response.